# Remove folders from search results (within library)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search, search-results

I have a library with lots of folders and documents. When I am using the default search box within the library (marked red)

[image]

I am always looking just for the documents, but the results include all the folders as well (I think the ones that have my query text in their URL property)

How do I remove all the folders from the results?

NOTE: I need this for only this particular library, it should not affect other search results in any way. Is there something in library settings that I'm missing?

I am using SharePoint Online

Comment: Have you tried adding IsDocument=1 to your query?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott It works if I add it in the search box, but I want it to be automatic

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you cannot change (apart from writing it directly into the search box) as answered in [this thread](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/444960).

I would suggest creating a new view and filtering the by file type:

- Type **is not equal to** (leave the box empty)

[image]

This way you can switch the view when you do not want folders to appear in your search results.

Comment: Thanks for the information Murilo, but the problem is that I'm also using custom tree view navigation on the library view page, so I can't exclude the folders :/ Do you know if there's a way t at least populate documents first in the results and then the folders?